# Ansible's 1password module fails with 'unknown flag: --output" message

Tags: ansible, 1password

I have set up a 'guest' user in 1password, and assigned a new vault to him. I've installed 1password's CLI utility ('op'). I can manually extract 1password secrets from the command line, or even from Ansible as:

```
- name: Retrieve password manually
  delegate_to: localhost
  ansible.builtin.command: 'op read "op://Ansible-Vaults/google/password"'
```

But I have been unable to use either ansible's 1password module community.general.onepassword_info or its lookup counterpart.
The following both fail with the following:

```
Failed to perform initial sign in to 1Password: [ERROR] 2023/09/21 18:25:16 unknown flag: --output
```

(Note that the play above runs just before, so it should already be logged in to 1password. And even if it wasn't, enough info was given to login again.)

```
- name: Retrieve password for HAL when not signed in to 1Password
  delegate_to: localhost
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: lookup('community.general.onepassword',
                google,
                section=TEST,
                field=password,
                vault="{{ opw_vault }}",
                domain="{{ opw_domain }}",
                subdomain="{{ opw_subdomain }}",
                master_password="{{ opw_password }}",
                username="{{  opw_username }}",
                secret_key="{{ opw_secret_key }}"
                )
```

```
- name: Get a password
  delegate_to: localhost
  community.general.onepassword_info:
    auto_login:
      master_password:  "{{ opw_password }}"
      secret_key:       "{{ opw_secret_key }}"
      subdomain:        "{{ opw_subdomain }}"
      username:         "{{ opw_username }}"
    search_terms:
      - name:    "google"
        field:   "password"      # optional, defaults to 'password'
        # section: Custom section name     # optional, defaults to 'None'
        vault:   "{{ opw_vault }}"       # optional, only necessary if there is more than 1 Vault available
  register: my_1password_item
  no_log: false                           # Don't want to log the secrets to the console!
```

Ansible Core 2.13.5

op version 2.21.0
Any help would be appreciated!

Update:
I was thinking that perhaps my "community general collection" was outdated. I updated it from 5.6.0 to 7.4.0, but it made no difference. Same error as before.